# Using waitcallback delegate in my own threadpool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to create my own custom threadpool. One of my functions have `WaitCallback` delegate as parameter and I'd like to use it like in basic threadpool to start it running in free thread from the set.

My problem is i do not know how to use `WaitCallback` delegate (the only examples of msdn and other sites are showing how to put method into threadpool with delegate) from the threadpool side.

Can you give me some light on how to get method from `WaitCallback` (so i can start it running in some thread), or if WaitCallback/threadpool works other way, how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hate to appear rude, but if you are unsure how to use a WaitCallback I very much doubt you will write a better threadpool than MS or the http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

WaitCallback is nothing more but a custom delegate type. If you see the declaration, you will find this `public delegate void WaitCallback(object state);`.
So you would use it to assign any method to it with input parameter of type `object`. Example `public void MyMethod(object parameter)` can be assigned to `WaitCallback wc = new WaitCallback(MyMethod)`.

Comment: Thanks for posting!

I know how to create delegate WaitCallback, but the problem is how to use this delegate.

for example:

    myfunction(WaitCallback wcd)
    {
    //what should i do now with wcd to be able to use method??
    }

I want to start running method in new thread. Is it possible now to use this method like this or threadpool is using WaitCallback some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you intend to do. If you want to fire a new thread, you can use:

```
public void ExecuteWork(WaitCallback wcb, Object param)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(
       o => 
       {
           wcb(o);
       });
    t.Start(param);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I wanted to fire a new thread using WaitCallback.